# Android emulator 2.0 crash when press power button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm using android emulator 2.0, all things is up-to-day. Device's details:

> Name: Nexus_5X_API_23
>   CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
>   Path: /home/khang/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_23.avd
>   Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 23)
>   Skin: nexus_5x
>   SD Card: /home/khang/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_23.avd/sdcard.img
>   hw.dPad: no
>   runtime.network.speed: full
>   hw.accelerometer: yes
>   hw.device.name: Nexus 5X
>   vm.heapSize: 100
>   hw.device.manufacturer: Google
>   hw.gps: yes
>   image.androidVersion.api: 23
>   hw.audioInput: yes
>   image.sysdir.1: system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86/
>   tag.id: google_apis
>   hw.camera.back: emulated
>   hw.mainKeys: no
>   AvdId: Nexus_5X_API_23
>   hw.camera.front: emulated
>   hw.lcd.density: 420
>   runtime.scalefactor: auto
>   avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 5X API 23
>   hw.gpu.mode: auto
>   hw.device.hash2: MD5:1be89bc42ec9644d4b77968b23474980
>   hw.ramSize: 1536
>   hw.trackBall: no
>   hw.battery: yes
>   hw.cpu.ncore: 2
>   hw.sdCard: yes
>   tag.display: Google APIs
>   runtime.network.latency: none
>   hw.keyboard: yes
>   hw.sensors.proximity: yes
>   disk.dataPartition.size: 800M
>   hw.sensors.orientation: yes
>   avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
>   hw.gpu.enabled: yes

I try to test my broadcast receiver which catch Lock/Unlock screen action. But I can't simulate it in Emulator 2.0 because whenever I press power button (or Ctrl P), android emulator auto close (no error message).

I thought power button cause the problem, but when I install an app which can force device sleeping (lock screen), my android emulator continue closing without any log or error message.

Have anyone known that problem? Ask me if you want to get more detail.

Comment: You really need a real device to test your application

Comment: Usual, I use Genymotion, but I remember that android emulator can turn on/off display (lock/unlock) like real device

Comment: Have you used any Bluetooth,sms or Wifi connection in your application.If so I request you to test your application in a real time device.Moreover always check your target API.

Comment: Same problem, same configuration, I'm on ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 3):

For the AVD config of the device you are running, edit the below Advanced settings:

Emulated-Performance:: Graphics: **Hardware**

Emulated-Performance:: Boot Option: **Cold Boot**

Emulated-Performance:: Multi-Core: **4** *(max on my system)*

Answer (score 0):

I see the same issue in the x86 API 23 emulator.  I wonder if it's a bug in that particular emulator image, since the power button works fine in the x86 API 22 emulator.  If you don't mind testing on a different version, you could try that.